# WinForm resolution

Tags: c#, winforms, screen-resolution

When I developed some winforms in C# and fixed a certain size for and run that program in another machine with smaller screen, most of the controls hide because the screen is smaller than mine. I think the best way is to fix the size in percentage according to the underlying Screen Resolution. So, how can I do so?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Control.Dock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock.aspx) and [`Control.Anchor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) Properties

[SEE HERE FOR SOME USAGE](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/net/nets13p1.html)

Comment: "_The requested URL /net/nets13p1.html was not found on this server._" . Could you update the link? Or better yet. Post the relevant content in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can find he screen resolution using the `System.Windows.Forms.Screen` class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.aspx

Answer (score 1):

What i understand from your question, says that few of your controls hide when your form resize.

You can use ANCHOR property of the form and controls to move them accordingly.

Hope it will work !!

Answer (score 0):

Use containers to house your controls. TableLayoutPanel would probably be a good choice. Set the TableLayoutPanels DockStyle to Fill. TableLayoutPanels only allow you to put one Control in each section, but Panels allow multiples so put a Panel in each section and set each Panels DockStyle to Fill. Arrange your controls in the panels and set each controls Anchor or DockStyle properties to keep them in location. Now, set your resolution to the lowest possible setting and build your form. If you follow the above steps, when you raise the resolution everything will be in the same relative location with the same relative size.

Why it works: Setting the tablelayoutpanels DockStyle to Fill makes it autosize with the parent form. Setting each panels DockStyle makes it autosize with the TableLayoutPanels sections. Anchoring/Docking controls inside the panels keeps the controls sizing and spacing relative to the panel.